# Clear proof of L'Hopital rule for $\infty/\infty$ form

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to understand the proof for L'Hopital rule for the $\infty/\infty$ form given [here](http://planetmath.org/ProofOfLHopitalsRuleForInftyinftyForm). It is really clear for most part except the last three steps, where it whizzes rapidly out of my grasp. How did they get that inequality mentioned there? Can someone please provide a simple explanation for those steps? Alternatively, is there another simpler proof for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You first proved, using Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem, that

$$\color{blue}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{1-\frac{g(c)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(c)}{f(x)}}\cdot\frac{f'(\xi_x)}{g'(\xi_x)}}$$

and also

$$\color{red}{\left|\frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)}-m\right|<\epsilon}\,,\,\,\text{for}\;\;0<|\xi-a|<\delta$$

and also, that

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1-\frac{g(c)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(c)}{f(x)}}=1\implies\color{green}{\left|\frac{1-\frac{g(c)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(c)}{f(x)}}-1\right|<\frac\epsilon{|m|+\epsilon}}\;,\;\;\text{for}\;\;0<|x-a|<\delta''<\delta$$

and from here

$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-m\right|\stackrel{\color{blue}{(*)}}=\left|\color{red}{\left(\frac{f'(\xi_x)}{g'(\xi_x)}-m\right)}+\frac{f'(\xi_x)}{g'(\xi_x)}\color{green}{\left(\frac{1-\frac{g(c)}{g(x)}}{1-\frac{f(c)}{f(x)}}-1\right)}\right|$$$${}$$

where $\color{blue}{(*)}\;$ is the first, blue, equality above (just open up parentheses and check!). You now have only to substitute the red and green inequalities

Comment: Could you please explain how you obtained the green inequality from the limit from which it is implied? I am not understanding that either!

Comment: @FreezingFire That's the definition: if $\;\lim\limits_{x\to a} h(x)=L\;$ then for any $\;E>0\;$ there exists $\;D>0\;$ such that $$|x-a|<D\implies |h(x)-L|<E$$ In your link's case, $\;E=\frac\epsilon{|m|+\epsilon}\;,\;\;D=\delta''\;$ , with $\;\epsilon>0\;$ an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Is the $E$ also an arbitrary choice, or is the value of $E$ determined somehow to be $\frac{\epsilon}{|m|+\epsilon}$?

Comment: @FreezingFire An arbitrary choice of $\;\epsilon\;$ , and then $\;E\;$ is what you wrote...which is also pretty arbitrary, of course, as it depends on $\;\epsilon$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof for the $\infty/ \infty$ case as $x \to a+,$ which I find easier to follow.

Note that we only need $g(x) \to \infty$.

If

$$L = \lim_{x \to a+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)},$$

then, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta_1 > 0 ,$ such that

$$L - \epsilon< \frac{f(x)- f(y)}{g(x) - g(y)} = \frac{f'(\xi)}{g'(\xi)} < L + \epsilon,$$

for $a < x < \xi <y < a + \delta_1,$ where the appearance of $\xi \in (x,y)$ follows from the MVT.

Hence,

$$L - \epsilon < \frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}- \frac{f(y)}{g(x)} }{1- \frac{g(y)}{g(x)} } < L + \epsilon, $$

and

$$ L - \epsilon  - \underbrace{\frac{(L - \epsilon)g(y)-f(y)}{g(x)}}_{C(x)}<  \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < L + \epsilon + \underbrace{\frac{(L + \epsilon)g(y)+f(y)}{g(x)}}_{D(x)}.  $$

Since $g(x) \to \infty$ there exists $\delta_2$ such that if $a < x < a + \delta_2$, with $y$ fixed,  we have $-\epsilon < C(x), \,\, D(x) < \epsilon.$

Hence, if $a < x < a+ \min(\delta_1,\delta_2),$ then we have

$$L - 2\epsilon < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < L + 2\epsilon.$$

Comment: Why do we use the same $\epsilon$ for both the limits (the first one for Cauchy's MVT and the second in the limit of $C(x)$ and $D(x)$)?

Comment: The first $\epsilon$ arises as $|f'(z)/g'(z) - L| < \epsilon$ when $a < z < a + \delta_1$ since $g'/f' \to L$ by hypothesis.  The MVT just says that for $x < y$ there is a point $\xi$ in between $x$ and $y$ such that $f'(\xi)/g'(\xi) = [f(x)-f(y)]/[g(x) - g(y)]$. Hence, $L - \epsilon < f'(\xi)/g'(\xi) < L + \epsilon$ and conseqently $L - \epsilon < [f(x) - f(y)]/[g(x)-g(y)] < L + \epsilon$. Now we split out $f(x)/g(x)$ and show it is sandwiched between $L - \epsilon -C(X)$ and $L+ \epsilon + D(x)$. But we can make $C(x)$ and $D(x)$ smaller than $\epsilon$ as well by making $x$ close to $a$.

Comment: Hence, by making $x$ sufficiently close to $a$ we have $|f(x)/g(x) - L| < 2\epsilon -- which means $f/g \to L$.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from [my blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-4.html).

---

There is another version of L'Hospital's Rule which is not so widely known and we state (and prove) it below:

*If $f(x), g(x)$ are differentiable in a certain neighborhood of $a$ (but not necessarily at $a$), $\lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{1}{g(x)} = 0$ (equivalently $|g(x)| \to \infty$ as $x \to a$) and $\lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$ then $\lim_{x \to a}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$*.

Thus in order to apply this version of L'Hospital's Rule we need to check that $|g(x)| \to \infty$ as $x \to a$. No check apart from differentiability is needed for the function $f(x)$. We prove this rule using the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of limit. Since $f'(x)/g'(x) \to L$ as $x \to a$, it follows that $f'(x)/g'(x)$ is bounded in a certain deleted neighborhood of $a$. Therefore there is a number $A > 0$ and a number $\delta_{1} > 0$ such that $$\left|\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\right| < A$$ for all $x$ with $0 < |x - a| < \delta_{1}$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then we know that there is a $\delta_{2} > 0$ such that $$\left|\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} - L\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$ for all $x$ with $0 < |x - a| < \delta_{2}$.

Let's consider the ratio $$\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{g(x) - g(y)}$$ where both $x, y$ are distinct points lying in deleted neighborhood $(a - \delta_{3}, a + \delta_{3}) - \{a\}$ of $a$ and $\delta_{3} = \min(\delta_{1}, \delta_{2})$. We can express this ratio as $$\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{g(x) - g(y)} = \dfrac{\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} - \dfrac{f(y)}{g(x)}}{1 - \dfrac{g(y)}{g(x)}}$$ and from this equation we obtain $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{g(x) - g(y)}\left(1 - \frac{g(y)}{g(x)}\right) + \frac{f(y)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}\left(1 - \frac{g(y)}{g(x)}\right) + \frac{f(y)}{g(x)}$$ where $c$ is some number between $x$ and $y$. Let $y$ have a fixed value in the deleted neighborhood $(a - \delta_{3}, a + \delta_{3}) - \{a\}$ of $a$. Then we know that $g(y)/g(x) \to 0, f(y)/g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a$. Hence there are positive numbers $\delta_{4}, \delta_{5}$ such that $$\left|\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{3A}$$ for all $x$ with $0 < |x - a| < \delta_{4}$ and $$\left|\frac{f(y)}{g(x)}\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$ for all $x$ with $0 < |x - a| < \delta_{5}$. Let $\delta = \min(\delta_{3}, \delta_{4}, \delta_{5})$ and let $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ then we have
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - L\right| &= \left|\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}\left(1 - \frac{g(y)}{g(x)}\right) + \frac{f(y)}{g(x)} - L\right|\notag\\
&= \left|\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} - L - \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}\cdot\frac{g(y)}{g(x)} + \frac{f(y)}{g(x)}\right|\notag\\
&\leq \left|\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} - L\right| + \left|\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}\right|\left|\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}\right| + \left|\frac{f(y)}{g(x)}\right|\notag\\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{3} + A\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{3A} + \frac{\epsilon}{3}\notag\\
&= \epsilon\notag
\end{align}
It now follows that $f(x)/g(x) \to L$ as $x \to a$ and the proof of the second version of L'Hospital's Rule is complete. Tt is easy to prove in similar manner that if $f'(x)/g'(x)$ tends to $\infty$ (or to $-\infty$) then so does $f(x)/g(x)$.